# How to remove the log info (TimeStamp etc.) from log file

Tags: linux, replace, command, remote-debugging, logfile

I have a log file which contains stuff like:

```
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: --> POST https://foo.com
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: Content-Length: 893
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: x-foo-id:blah
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: Authorization: Bearer ***
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: 
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: {"url_tags":"utm_campaign"}
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: --> END POST (893-byte body)
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: <-- 400 Bad Request https://foo.com (4443ms)
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: Vary: Accept-Encoding
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: x-aax_id: 555
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: x-app-usage: {"call_count":0,"total_cputime":0,"total_time":0}
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "invalid_request" "Invalid parameter"
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: version: v0.122
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: Pragma: no-cache
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: x-xxx-aaa: 123475
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: Cache-Control: no-store
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: x-aa_id: bfi742bfsa
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: Date: Wed, 03 Apr 2019 22:30:16 GMT
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: Connection: keep-alive
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: 
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: {"error":{"message":"Invalid parameter"}}
2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement: <-- END HTTP (294-byte body)
```

Is there any way in which I can remove all occurrences of `2019-04-03 22:30:16,772 [pool-9-thread-1] INFO  wire.CampaignManagement:` using Linux commands?

Note: I am working on a remote machine so I can't use VSCode or Sublime to edit this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -i -pe 's/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3}\d+\[pool-\d+-thread-\d+\]\d+(?:INFO|DEBUG)\d+wire\.CampaignManagement://'  file
```

Comment: I'm guessing you got a -1 because, even though it was not explicit, the date/time, thread name, severity and class name are subject to change.

Answer (score 0):

Same as @Gilles Quenot : sed.

As an example of a partially more generic version (although not elegant), this could be used instead:

```
   sed 's/[[:digit:]]\{4\}-[[:digit:]]\{2\}-[[:digit:]]\{2\} [[:digit:]]\{1,2\}:[[:digit:]]\{1,2\}:[[:digit:]]\{1,2\},[[:digit:]]\{1,3\} \[pool-9-thread-1\] \(INFO\|DEBUG\)  wire.CampaignManagement://' file
```

If the tread, log level or name is subject to change, match it accordingly.